# merb_auth_password_slice does not maintain the session

Tags: ruby, merb, merb-auth

Having integrated `merb_auth_password_slice` as per the README, I can successfully login as `redirect_after_login` is being triggered, although `session.authenticated?` returns false.

Just trying the basic auth strategy for now (password form), can't seem to get it working, any ideas?

My init file:

```
require 'dm-validations'

dependencies "merb-more", "merb_helpers", "merb-slices", "merb_auth_password_slice"


Merb::BootLoader.before_app_loads do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://config/dev.db")
end

Merb::BootLoader.after_app_loads do
    # have already done this
    # raise "You must specify a valid openid in Merb.root/config/open_id to use this example app" unless File.exists?(Merb.root / "config" / "open_id")
    # # DataMapper.auto_migrate!
    # User.create(:login => "admin", 
    #             :password => "password", :password_confirmation => "password", 
    #             :email => "admin@example.com", 
    #             :identity_url => File.read(Merb.root / "config" / "open_id"))
end

Merb::Config.use do |c|
  c[:session_secret_key]  = 'my key'
  c[:session_store] = 'cookie'
end
```

Setup.rb

```
class Authentication

  def store_user(user)
    return nil unless user
    user.id
  end

  def fetch_user(session_info)
    User.get(session_info)
  end

end # Authentication
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  # before(nil, :only => [:update, :destroy]) { session.abandon! }
```

This is the culprit in the slice's session controller